# How to validate complete cart and prevent line item is updated in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am using `woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated` for complete cart validation. The cart still gets updated even after `$cart_updated` is made false.

Is this the proper usage of this filter or I am doing something wrong?

I dont want to use `woocommerce_update_cart_validation` as it validates item by item in cart rather than the complete cart as a whole

```php
function filter_woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated( $cart_updated ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();   
    //iterate thru all cart items
    foreach($cart_items as $cart_item) {
        $Availability=check_availability();
        if('PAST_NA'==$Availability) {
            $cart_updated = false;
            wc_add_notice( 'Items not available for the selected dates', 'error' );
            return $cart_updated;

        }
        elseif('CART_NA'==$Availability) {
            $cart_updated = false;
            wc_add_notice('Your cart has more than available items for the selected dates', 'error' );
            return $cart_updated;
        }
        else{
            $cart_updated=true;
        }

    }
     return $cart_updated;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'filter_woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: `$Availability = check_availability();` where is `check_availability();` set 
or specified?

Comment: In the same file. I am getting proper response from this function check_availability(). The variable $cart_updated is getting updated appropriately but the cart still gets updated

Comment: To give an appropriate answer to your question it might be interesting to add that code as well as an explanation of what exactly you want to do? 
you do not want to use a certain hook while asking if you are doing something wrong,  difficult to answer in this way

Comment: I can add the code but it is a very big one. Even if I remove the entire code and only return `$cart_updated=false`, the cart is still updating. My requirement is to avoid cart update based on certain conditions. Is this the right filter ? If yes, what could be the possible reasons for `$cart_updated=false` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L660-L678). First you have the validation hook per item (`woocommerce_update_cart_validation`), on line 670 (`$passed_validation`) is true, so the item is already passed and updated and `woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated` is to late for validation.

Proof of concept

```php
function filter_woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated( $cart_updated ) {
    $cart_updated = false;

    if ( $cart_updated == false ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'my error', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }

    return $cart_updated;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'filter_woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 10, 1 );
```

---

EDIT:

Maybe you can still use `woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated` where you will adjust the updated item again with [`WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity );`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartset_quantity/).

As far as I know there is no hook that prevents updating per item and in the meantime applies a check to the entire shopping cart

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r. Seems `woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated` will be the wrong filter in this case. Is there any other way by which I can validate cart as a whole, `woocommerce_update_cart_validation` validates item by item. Lets say we change quantity for item1 is 3->4 and item2 is 5->6. I want to use this quantity 4 and 6 at the same time. But with `woocommerce_update_cart_validation`, I will only have quantity info about one item at a time.

Comment: well you could use `$cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();` in `woocommerce_update_cart_validation` 
with which you have the contents of the entire shopping cart. With some extra code you can determine which is the current item being updated by the hook and then exclude / apply in the loop

Comment: `$cart_items` will provide me cart info before update (it will provide 3 and 5, I need 4 and 6)

Comment: I understand, maybe you can still use `woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated` 
where you will adjust the updated item again with (`WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity );`). As far as I know there is no hook that prevents updating per item and in the meantime applies a check to the entire shopping cart

Comment: This looks like a nice idea. It will serve the purpose. Can you post this as an answer. I will accept. Thanks for your time and efforts.